# Raw SQL_Flask SQLAlchemy: Use List IN Bind Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I pass a list inside ":songs"?

The raw SQL will work if I pass in a key:value pair but not when I attempt to pass in a list. I get an AttributeError: list object has no attribute 'keys.'

```
    songs = ('Song1', 'Song2', 'Song3', 'Song4', 'Song5')
    engine = app.db.engine
    connection = engine.connect()
    rawSqlResult = text(
    "SELECT * FROM AlbumView WHERE Song IN :songs")
    queryResult = connection.execute(rawSqlResult, songs)

    tempDict, resultList = {}, []
    for rowproxy in queryResult:
        for tup in rowproxy.items():
            tempDict = {**tempDict, **{tup[0]: tup[1]}}
        resultList.append(tempDict)
        print(resultList)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This approach](https://gist.github.com/pawl/555e5eecce77d4de0ada) solved my issue:

```
my_list = ['peach', 'grape', 'apple']
query_parameters = {}
counter = 1
for list_item in my_list:
    query_parameters["list_item" + str(counter)] = list_item
    counter += 1

where_clause = 'fruits IN(:' + ",:".join(query_parameters.keys()) + ')' # create clause to be inserted into query
query_text = db.text("""
    SELECT fruits
    FROM table
    WHERE """ + where_clause + """ """)

result = db.engine.execute(query_text, **query_parameters)
```